# Obtaining real-space correlations from reciprocal space correlations

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, correlation-functions

Consider a system of Ising variable $s = \pm 1$ on a rectangular lattice which has open boundary conditions on the top and bottom and periodic boundary conditions to the left and right. In other words, a cylinder. Specifically, the lattice is as shown here:

[image]

where the spins live at the vertices and the lines denote bonds between them. This system is essentially one dimensional. The unit cell can be defined to span the vertical direction, and in the image above would have 24 spins in it. Each spin in the unit cell occupies a separate one-dimensional sublattice. This cell is repeated by translation along the horizontal direction. We can define a reciprocal lattice which is also one-dimensional, with reciprocal lattice vectors $\mathbf{q}_\perp$. We can therefore define a Fourier transform of the spin variables on each sublattice $\alpha$ as

$$s_\alpha(\mathbf{q}_\perp) = \frac{1}{n_c} \sum_{i} e^{-i(\mathbf{r}_i+\mathbf{r}_\alpha)\cdot \mathbf{q}_\perp} s_\alpha(\mathbf{r}_i) $$

where $\mathbf{r}_i$ denotes the $i$'th unit cell and $\mathbf{r}_\alpha$ denotes the position the $\alpha$ sublattice within a unit cell, and $n_c$ is the number of unit cells in the lattice (20 in the picture above). Note that I am treating $\mathbf{q}_\perp$ as a vector $(qx,0)$.

I have already found a method by which to compute the reciprocal space correlation functions $\left< s_\alpha(-\mathbf{q}_\perp) s_\beta(\mathbf{q}_\perp) \right>$. The spin structure factor is defined as the Fourier transform of the real space correlation matrix

$$S(\mathbf{q}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{ij} e^{-i(\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j)\cdot \mathbf{q} }\left<s_i s_j\right>$$

where the sum is over all $N$ spins in the lattice, and now $\mathbf{q}$ is a two-dimensional wave vector $(q_x,q_y)$. This can be shown to reduce to

$$S(\mathbf{q}) = \frac{1}{n_s}\sum_{\alpha,\beta} e^{iq_y(\mathbf{r}_\alpha - \mathbf{r}_\beta)\cdot\hat{\mathbf{y}} }\left< s_\alpha(-\mathbf{q}_\perp) s_\beta(\mathbf{q}_\perp) \right>$$

where $\mathbf{q}_\perp = q_x \hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and $n_s$ is the number of spins in a unit cell (or the number of sublattices). Now I wish to invert this relationship to get back to the real space correlators $\left<s_i s_j\right>$, but I cannot figure out how to do this. But my primary question is,

How do I obtain $\left<s_i s_j\right>$ from $S(\mathbf{q})$ or from $\left< s_\alpha(-\mathbf{q}_\perp) s_\beta(\mathbf{q}_\perp) \right>$.

I am also working with similar 3D systems, so I would prefer a solution which works in 3D as well. All of the equations should generalize in the obvious way.